# We offered 1$ reimbursement. Is this usage correct?

Tags: word-usage

I came across this sentence:

```
We offered 1$ reimbursement for [...]
```

Is that correct? I'm not sure, but I think it should be:

```
We offered a 1$ reimbursement for [...]
```

or

```
We offered 1$ in reimbursement for [..]
```

Comment: All should be $1.

Comment: Did you offer it in the past, or are you offering it now?

Comment: @HotLicks It was offered and paid for in the past

Comment: Then any of the three is valid, after you reposition the "$".  2 or 3 is probably preferred, with the decision base on the "tone" of the writing.

Comment: The dollar sign is written before the number but pronounced afterwards, like the English Pound is.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen options 1 or 2 used professionally. But colloquially those are the most popular choices.

Option 2 is widely used and grammatically acceptable but its use in a formal setting is questionable.

In formal writing, I would recommend option 3

Other options I've seen used include

- We offered a reimbursement of $1 for...
- We offered $1 as reimbursement for...